# Find the value of $\ a\ $ given that $\ y=4x+x^2-ax^3\ $ is concave for $\ x<3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, solution-verification, convex-analysis

> Find the value of $\ a\ $ given that $\ y=4x+x^2-ax^3\ $ is concave for $\
> x<3.$

This is a question from my textbook I am working on. I assume it means *for all $\ x<3.$*

The answer in the back is $\ a=\frac{1}{9},\ $ but I think this is wrong based on the [graph on WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x%2Bx%5E2-1%2F9x%5E3)

My attempt, which I want to confirm if it is correct or not:

$y=f(x)\ $ concave for $\ x<3\ \implies\ f''(x)<0\ $ for $\ x<3.$

$f''(x)=-6ax+2.$

$f''(x)<0\implies -6ax+2<0\implies 6ax>2\ $ for all $\ x<3.$

Therefore, $\ a> \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{x}\ $ for all $\ 0<x<3,$

and $\ a< \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{x}\ $ for all $\ x<0.$

But no real $\ a\ $ satisfies both these inequalities.

Comment: Your title says "convex" but your work is for "concave"?

Comment: @angryavian thanks: just fixed that

Comment: A function $f$ is concave if $-f$ is convex

Comment: I suspect it is a typo and they meant $x>3$.

Comment: Your work seems correct. Perhaps the problem meant "$x > 3$" but even then any $a \ge 1/9$ will work, not just $a=1/9$.

Comment: @Matthew Daly Yes that is what I suspected. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument works perfectly. I suspect it is a typo. The author meant to write "convex" instead of "concave".